# Z-index issue with image

Tags: css

I've this code

```css
.logo {
   display: block;
   z-index: 2;
}

.ellipse {
  background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
    left: 80px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  top: 130px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bloc-logo">
    <div class="logo"><img src="http://1389blog.com/pix/happy-cat-wallpaper-thumbnail.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="fff" /></div>
    <div class="ellipse"></div>
</div>
```

I want the image be over the rounded div. I try with z-index but it does not work.

Thanks for you help !

Comment: set `z-index` of the ellipse to -1

Answer (score 1):

Set the z-index to -1 on the .ellipse. Please see codepen provided and relevant code.

```
.ellipse {
  background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
    left: 80px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  top: 130px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

http://codepen.io/Billy-Purvis/pen/oXEEaM

Answer (score 1):

To use z-index, an element needs to be positioned (relative, fixed or absolute). However, you don't need to give it any left or right attributes for it to work.

```css
.logo {
   display: block;
   position:relative;
   z-index: 2;
}

.ellipse {
  background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
    left: 80px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  top: 130px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="bloc-logo">
    <div class="logo"><img src="http://1389blog.com/pix/happy-cat-wallpaper-thumbnail.jpg" width="150" height="150" alt="fff" /></div>
    <div class="ellipse"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the z-index property of the 'ellipse' class as -1.

```
.ellipse {
  background: red none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
    left: 80px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -50px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  top: 130px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

But is this what you really need. Please tell if you need any more enhancements.